# How to convert a web app to android app without 'url' in offline mode?

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications, offline

I make a web app using HTML canvas.I want to convert my web app to an android app. But main problem is that my app's all file in my device offline and I have no url of my HTML web app project but have only files of project. Can anyone tell me how to convert my HTML project to android app?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I willl tell you how to get started with creating a basic app with local HTML pages.

1. Download Android Studio IDE.
2. Create Android project with Empty Activity.
3. Put all your html pages  in asset folder:

[image: add android assets folder]

4. Add `WebView` to your view (replace the code in your `activity_main.xml` file with this)

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>  android:layout_width="match_parent"
>  android:background="#FFFFFF"
>  android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
> <WebView
>  android:layout_width="match_parent"
>  android:id="@+id/webView"
>  android:layout_height="match_parent"
>  android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

5. Load the HTML pages in `WebView` from your `Activity` class in `onCreate()`:

   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

   `WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);`

   `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xyz.html");`

To know more on how to use `WebView` in Android app efficiently refer this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `project.js` (javascript file)? If your project only contains Html, css, and javascript, the easiest way is using [Ionic framework](https://ionicframework.com/). Start with `node.js`. First, convert your project into a `node` project and then convert it to an `ionic` project.